# How do I store static content of a web page in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dojo

This is what I am trying to accomplish: 
Get the static content of an 'external' url and check it for certain keywords for example, "User Guide" or "page not found".

I tried to use Ajax, dojo.xhr etc., but they don't support cross domain. In my case it is an external url. Also, I cannot use jQuery.

I also looked at dojo.io.iframe but I couldn't find useful example to accomplish this.

A dojo.io.iframe example would be really helpful.
Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: php? file_get_contents(yourTargetURL)? then call that web service with ajax...

Comment: I cannot use php. All I am allowed to use is html and javascript. In addition to that, I can also use javascript's dojo library. Or any google api would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers restrict the use of cross-domain scripting. If you're the maintainer of the server, read [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to get knowledge on how to enable cross-site scripting on your website.

**EDIT**: To check whether an external site is down or not, you could use this method. That external site is required to have an image file. Most sites have a file called `favicon.ico` at their root directory.

Example, testing whether http://www.google.com/ is online or not.

```
var test = new Image();

//If you're sure that the element is not a JavaScript file
//var test = document.createElement("script");

//If you're sure that the external website is reliable, you can use:
//var test = document.createElement("iframe");

function rmtmp(){if(tmp.parentNode)tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);}
function online(){
    //The website is likely to be up and running.
    rmtmp();
}
function offline(){
    //The file is not a valid image file, or the website is down.
    rmtmp();
    alert("Something bad happened.");
}
if (window.addEventListener){
    test.addEventListener("load", online, true);
    test.addEventListener("error", offline, true);
} else if(window.attachEvent){
    test.attachEvent("onload", online);
    test.attachEvent("onerror", offline);
} else {
    test.onload = online;
    test.onerror = offline;
}

test.src = "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico?"+(new Date).getTime();
 /* "+ (new Date).getTime()" is needed to ensure that every new attempt
    doesn't get a cached version of the image */
if(/^iframe|script$/i.test(test.tagName)){
    test.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(test);
}
```

This will only work with image resources. Read the comments to see how to use other sources.

Comment: This is not cross site scripting. It is just about loading the contents of a website into a javascript variable. Also I don't have access to the server side code. I can make changes only on the client side. And the website I am trying to access is external.

Comment: Cross-*domain* scripting. If your website is hosted at http://foo.com, and the "external source" is served at http://bar.com, the Same-origin policy prevents you from getting access to that source. Whether you're using a frame, XMLHttpRequest or not. Your **only** option to retrieve JavaScript variables from an external website is to include them using `<script src-"http://external.com/vars.js"></script>`, provided that these are served as valid JavaScript variables.

Comment: So, is there a way to load the static content of a cross domain into a variable in javascript? I tried looking at dojo.io.iframe. They seem to accomplish this but I couldn't find any helpful examples.  Here is the link to dojo.io.iframe: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/io/iframe.html

Comment: "Static" in the context of webpages: No, you can **not** access external (web) resources through AJAX or frames. A side note, about Stack Overflow (since you're new): If you find an answer helpful, use the *Vote up* feature. If the answer is an answer to your question: Use *Accept* feature. But do NOT add another reply (answer) with a "Thank you!" message. For more information, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Okay. Let me rephrase my question. The scenario: I have a webpage www.A.com, and I have a link that links to a different domain (B.com). That link can sometime be taken down (unpublished) therefore, I need to check if that link has been taken down or not. If it has been taken down, the link does not 'attempt' to redirect to that url. Otherwise, it does. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @Sunny, See my updated answer. I've included some methods for that specific case.

Comment: Thanks so far  for your help, but the problem is that the root of the website will 'never' be down. It is only the a specific url that might get 'unpublished' and the only way to tell that is to read the message posted on that webpage which will contain keywords like "unpublished", "not found" etc..

Comment: Read the comments. If you're sure that the site is safe (no malicious scripts, or anti-frame measures), use the iframe method. If you're sure that it's never going to be a valid JavaScript resource, use the `script` method (it will generate errors in the error console, though).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js" type="text/javascript" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<script>
    dojo.require("dojo.io.script");
</script>

<script>
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

  dojo.io.script.get({

    url: "http://badlink.google.com/",
    //url: "http://www.google.com/",

    load: function(response, ioArgs) {
        //if no (http) error, it means the link works
        alert("yes, the url works!")
    }

  });
});
</script>
```